# is it possible to redirect to other page after interval

Tags: c#, html, .net

I want my page to redirect to other page after 3 seconds.
I know i can use:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='http://.....com/
```

i need that the url will contain my page location and not an http url.
something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url="~/GUI/blabla.aspx"">
```

Is that can be done without javascript or ajax, maybe in cs code or the html ?

Comment: This is a pretty evil way to redirect (http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback), but you can use a relative URL just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='<%= ResolveUrl("~/GUI/blabla.aspx") %>'" />
```

`<%= ResolveUrl("~/GUI/blabla.aspx") %>` will execute server side rendering the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

```
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
```

this is the php way to set header witch will redirect you to wherever.php in 5 seconds.